# Left join attempt in Linq Expression returning unwanted null item

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have the following linq expression:

```
var list = _context.Transactions.Where(x => x.Date >= request.DateStart && x.Date <= request.DateEnd)
            .Include(x => x.Organisation).DefaultIfEmpty()
            .ToList();
```

The Query is attempting to perform a left join on Transactions when a OraganisationID is present.  In SQL it, the equivalent query would be:

```
select * from Transactions t 
where t.Date > request.DateStart AND T.Date <= request.DateEnd
left join Organisation o ON t.OrganisationId = o.OrganisationId
```

The linq expression works great except for when there are no matches for Transactions between the supplied dates, at which point it should return 0 results but actually returns one null item in the list.

I suspect this is related to the Include.(..).DefaultIfEmpty() but I am not sure how to go about resolving it.

The linq query should do the following

- When transactions do match, it should return all transactions along with the corresponding Organisation Entity based on Transactions.OrganisationId (this works)
- When a Transaction contains no matching Organisation it should return null for the Oragnisation Entity but still retuirn the Transaction entity itself (this works)
- When No Transactions match the dates provided, it should return 0 results instead of 1 null result (this does not work)

Below is the Transction Entity:

```
public class Transaction
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; } = default!;
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; } = 0;
        
    [ForeignKey("OrganisationId")]
    public Organisation? Organisation { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you really want an inner join, not a left join. Returning a null for when there is no right-side match is exactly what a left join does.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I do need a left join as not every transaction will have a matching Organisation, in these cases it should returns the transaction entity but a null for the Organisation.  This already works.  However, the problem is that when no transactions are returns, the query still returns one null item in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultIfEmpty()` is not needed here, `Include` already should perform left join for non-required relations, just remove it:

```cs
var list = _context.Transactions
    .Where(x => x.Date >= request.DateStart && x.Date <= request.DateEnd)
    .Include(x => x.Organisation)
    .ToList();
```

As for the `null` element for empty result, from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.defaultifempty?view=net-7.0):

> Returns the elements in a sequence or a default valued singleton collection if the sequence is empty.

`DefaultIfEmpty` is applied to your `IQueryable<Transaction>`, hence the output of collection with single default element (i.e. `null`).

**UPD**

To correctly represent non-required relation with explicit key specification, key should be nullable

```cs
public class Transaction
{
    // ...
    public int? OrganisationId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, if a Transaction.OrganisationId does not have a matching Organisation, the Transaction row itself is not returned thus breaking the left join relationship which I need to keep.

Comment: @MusaffarPatel then it seems that you need to fix the entities - for later EF Core with nullable reference types enabled `Transaction.OrganisationId` and `Transaction.Organisation` should be marked as nullable. The approach itself was tested many times - for correctly set up entities the query results in left join with correctly returned entries with null relations.

Comment: Thanks, while my Organisation entity was nullable, the OrganisationId was not nullable, making it nullable fixed the issue - a lesson for the future.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when your list is empty the `DefaultIfEmpty()` return specified value in a singleton collection , not 0 result

Comment: When no transactions are returned, It returns a list with one item and that item is null.  I need it to return zero results when no transactions are returned in the query but still maintain the left join relationship with the Organisation entity for when there are transactions